# Get permission for registry key

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry

Trying to change value `HideBasedOnVelocityId` to `ShowBasedOnVelocityId` in registry `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cmd`. For this purpose I'm trying to get permissions:

[image]

[image]

Got error:

[image]

```
---------------------------
Windows Security
---------------------------
Unable to save permission changes on cmd.
Access is denied.
```

How to get permissions for this registry key?

Answer (score 0):

You need to take ownership of the registry key and then assign the permissions accordingly.

**Changing Ownership of a Registry Key**

- Select the key for which you want to change ownership.
- On the Edit menu, click Permissions.
- Click Advanced, and then click "Change".
- Under "Select User or Group", type `administrators` and click OK.
- Now, assign the required permissions for the key.

For more information, you may read the article [Take Ownership of a Registry Key And Assign Full Permissions](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/how-to-take-ownership-of-registry-keys-and-assign-full-permissions/).

Comment: @vico: Note that after you do this change, you need to restore the owner to `TrustedInstaller`. See [link](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/restore-owner-file-folder-registry-key-trustedinstaller-windows/).